# variable that can hold a multiple values in sql

Tags: sql-server-2008

i am facing a slite problem in sql server 2008 and here is the situation

```
IF @PatCntFamNbr is not null 
BEGIN

select  t.Cntid AS Center , t.PatFName AS FirstName   , t.PatMName AS MiddleName , t.PatLName AS     LastName  
from tblpatient t INNER JOIN  TblPatientCentres p
 ON   p.PatID_fk = t.PatId_PK
where   p.CentreID_fk=@cntid  and @patid in (select patid_fk from tblpatientcentres where cntfammbnbr=@cntfammbnbr)
END
```

my major problem is that this must show lots of names that belongs to the same family and the variable @patis is accepting only one variable and this is not allowing the procedure to work properly

i will be really thankful for any help

Answer (score 1):

If you need a variable that can hold multiple values then you should use a [Table Variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms175010.aspx)
IE something like `DECLARE @patid TABLE(ID INT)`

If you need the variable to be passed in via a client application then research table valued types

However your query doesnt look like it needs either - it just needs fixing...

```
IF @PatCntFamNbr is not null 
BEGIN

select  t.Cntid AS Center , t.PatFName AS FirstName   , t.PatMName AS MiddleName , t.PatLName AS     LastName  
from tblpatient t INNER JOIN  TblPatientCentres p
 ON   p.PatID_fk = t.PatId_PK
where   p.CentreID_fk=@cntid  and p.cntfammbnbr=@cntfammbnbr -- this is all you need
END
```